# Dropdown Selection in Selenium does change the selection but not the HTML Page

Tags: java, html, selenium, selection, dropdown

I have a problem with Selenium and Java.
I try to get some informations from a HTML page with a dropdown-menu into my Java Project.
(The URL does not change when i use different selections of the drop down menu)

I tried many ways to get an other selection. At this point I am here:

```
    WebElement DropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_DropDownMenu"));
    DropDown.click();
    DropDown = DropDown.findElement(By.xpath(".//option[normalize-space(text())='WantedOption']"));
    DropDown.click();
```

This method does change the selection but not the information that should be displayed on the HTML Page. (When I print the selection it says "[]" which is the right selection value)

The page Text ist after my selection still the same.

P.S.: Sorry for my "not the best" english I hope you understand what I mean.

Edit:

```
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.hotslogs.com/Sitewide/HeroAndMapStatistics");
    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_DropDownGameMode")));
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Team League");
    String pageText = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_RadGridMapStatistics")).getText();
    System.out.println(pageText);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`Select` class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) that abstracts away dealing with `select->option` blocks, try it:

```
Select dropdown = Select(driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_DropDownMenu")));

dropdown.selectByVisibleText("WantedOption");
```

Comment: I have still the same Problem. When I print out the page Text after changing the selection I get the Text which is also shown with the standard selection.

Comment: @JosephGordan is it a public site under the test?

Comment: What do you mean witg public site?

Comment: @JosephGordan can I actually see the problem, or is this your company internal web-site and this is impossible? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have any persmissions for this Website. Its just a HTML page in the world wide web which has information in tables that i want to use. Via the drop down menu i can choose a table. But like i explained the Selection with selenium does not have any effect on the table. (When i choose a dropdown Selection with a real Browser and not in Java it works of course)

Comment: I try to change the selection from Heroe League to Team League: http://www.hotslogs.com/Sitewide/HeroAndMapStatistics

Comment: @JosephGordan interesting, it actually works for me. Have you changed the id to "MainContent_DropDownGameMode" and the "WantedOption" to "Team League"? If yes, can you show the complete code you have so far? (please edit the question and include it into it) Thanks.

Comment: @JosephGordan have you tried other drivers beside HTML Unit?

Comment: until now i didn't. I will try this evening when i am at home. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: do you have an answer for me?

Comment: @JosephGordan there are multiple options, but I don't know what your constraints are.

Comment: well i tried to use the firefox driver. Then a browser window opened and the website opened with the right dropdown selection. But I don't want to get an opened browser... Like I said I just want to get the Page Text with the right dropdown selection. I am not very familiar with selenium, because I use it for this project the first time. Maybe you can give me a code which could solve my problem? Maybe you even have a better solution then selenium for my problem. I really don't come any further.